# Why does my Minecraft lag even though we upgraded the internet modem?

Tags: lag

I made my mum upgrade my internet modem, because my Minecraft lags when she’s on YouTube. I still lag now. Why is this? None of my friends have lag hops when playing.

Is my Minecraft too laggy or what is the issue? I asked my it teacher and he said someone is stealing my Internet is this true?

Comment: If your and your moms computer are connected via Wifi then most likely the Internet speed is not the problem but the Wifi speed. Don't forget that Wifi uses the air - which is a shared medium (speed splits up between all users in the area). And don't believe the Wifi speed values for the router advertisements - those are only theoretical raw values -> connect your PC via cable if you can.

Comment: What ISP do you use? Which plan do you have? What make and model is your modem/router?

Comment: thanx for the help, we were with iinet but now with Telstra, the modem is a f@st 5355 we have a 10 down/2 up plan

Comment: my teacher said people can steal my internet on the telstra air thing also

Comment: imo Telstra Air should always be disabled but it can only be turned off by ringing telstra direct, Theres no reason to share your bandwidth with someone else for free, saying that i dont think anyone really uses it.

Comment: You say you upgraded the “Internet modem.” Does this mean your mum upgraded the internet service from the ISP? Or are you mixing up “modem” with “router?” Because upgrading a router wouldn’t improve Internet speed.

Comment: A Slow internet does not necessarily increase latency (ping). What I suspect is your game performance is poor, and you are identifying it as latency, when it actually is caused by system performance.

Comment: If you have switched ISPs completely then the issue is not just internet speed. There could be something off on your setup to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without other people stealing your internet bandwidth illegally or legally, 10 MBit/s is probably too slow—that is if you’re even getting the full 10 MBit/s. Due to the burst-y nature of web surfing, it is bound to disturb applications that require steady bandwidth (like online gaming). Youtube specifically can easily require 2.5+ MBit/s at higher resolutions.

If you’re using Wi-Fi in your home, that may also be a problem, especially concerning potential interference.

Note that fixed wireless broadband (something that Telstra appears to be pushing) may be unsuitable for gaming, depending on local conditions. Your current router is a DSL router, so you appear to not have wireless broadband currently.

If you can access the router’s web interface, you may be able to see the actual bandwidth you’re getting. Additionally, you can use a speed test service like [fast.com](https://fast.com) (hosted by Netflix) to check the actual bandwidth. You may also want to use the [DSLReports speed test](http://dslreports.com/speedtest) because it collects metrics relevant to gamers (namely buffer bloat).

Comment: There is a key thing missing from this question: The original poster states, “…upgrade my internet modem.” Does that mean the modem was upgraded, the speed on the modem is upgraded or is the original poster mixing up “modem” with “router?”

Comment: @JakeGould It’s in the comments, OP says they switched from iinet to Telstra.

Comment: Good to know. So this isn’t just a case of the original ISP bumping up speeds, but the family moving to a completely different ISP. As you state, this all points to this not being an ISP issue but rather a system issue on the original poster’s side.